# Variable t is never used

Tags: android, variables

this belove is my load_data java class. I got only the variable s displayed on screen because "variable t is never used". Could someone please tell me where I can find it?

```
package etn.transport.transporteexpress;

import...

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class display_clicked_load extends AppCompatActivity {

    String id;
    String loginemail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_clicked_load);
        mLockScreenRotation();
        Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendbutton);

        id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
        String shipping_date = getIntent().getStringExtra("shipping_date");
        String shipping_time = getIntent().getStringExtra("shipping_time");
        String shipping_address_address = getIntent().getStringExtra("shipping_address_address");
        String shipping_address_postal_code = getIntent().getStringExtra("shipping_address_postal_code");
        String shipping_address_city = getIntent().getStringExtra("shipping_address_city");
        String shipping_address_nation = getIntent().getStringExtra("shipping_address_nation");
        String description = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");
        String weight = getIntent().getStringExtra("weight");
        String destination_date = getIntent().getStringExtra("destination_date");
        String destination_time = getIntent().getStringExtra("destination_time");
        String destination_address_address = getIntent().getStringExtra("destination_address_address");
        String destination_address_postal_code = getIntent().getStringExtra("destination_address_postal_code");
        String destination_address_city = getIntent().getStringExtra("destination_address_city");
        String destination_address_nation = getIntent().getStringExtra("destination_address_nation");

        //loginemail = getIntent().getStringExtra("loginemail");

        loginemail=global.email1;

        TextView loaddate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtloaddate);
        TextView loadtime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtloadtime);
        TextView loadplace = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtloadplace);
        TextView txtdesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdescription);
        TextView txtweight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtweight);
        TextView txtdestdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdestinationdate);
        TextView txtdesttime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdestinationtime);
        TextView txtdestplace = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdestplace);

       /* String s = "<b>Shipping Date:</b>" + shipping_date.toString();
        loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));

        String t = "<b>Time:</b>" + shipping_time.toString();
        loadtime.setText(Html.fromHtml(t));

        String u = "<b>shipping_address</b>" + shipping_address_address.toString();
        loadplace.setText(Html.fromHtml(u));

        String v = "<b>Description:</b>" + description.toString();
        txtdesc.setText(Html.fromHtml(v));

        String w = "<b>Weight:</b>" + weight.toString() + " KG";
        txtweight.setText(Html.fromHtml(w));

        String x = "<b>Destination Date:</b>" + destination_date.toString();
        txtdestdate.setText(Html.fromHtml(x));

        String y = "<b>Time:</b>" + destination_time.toString();
        txtdesttime.setText(Html.fromHtml(y));

        String z = "<b>Destination Address:</b>" + destination_address_address.toString();
        txtdestplace.setText(Html.fromHtml(z));
*/


        String s = getResources().getString(R.string.shipping_date, shipping_date.toString());
        loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
        String t= getResources().getString(R.string.shipping_time, shipping_time.toString());
       /* loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(t));
        String u= getResources().getString(R.string.shipping_address_c, shipping_address_address.toString());
        loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(u));
        String v= getResources().getString(R.string.transport_description_c, description.toString());
        loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(v));
        String w= getResources().getString(R.string.weight, weight.toString());
        loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(w));
        String x= getResources().getString(R.string.destination_date, shipping_date.toString());
        loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(x));
        String z= getResources().getString(R.string.destination_time, destination_time.toString());
        loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(y));
        String z= getResources().getString(R.string.destination_address, destination_address.toString());
        loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(z));
       /* loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
       loadtime.setText("Time:" + shipping_time.toString());
        loadplace.setText("Shipping Address:" + shipping_address_address);
        txtdesc.setText("Description:" + description);
        txtweight.setText("Weight: " + weight + " KG");
        txtdestdate.setText("Destination Date:" + destination_date.toString());
        txtdesttime.setText("Time:" + destination_time.toString());
        txtdestplace.setText("Destination Address:" + destination_address_address);
*/

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                new myTask().execute();

            }
        });

    }

    class myTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.d("inside", "onPre");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Log.d("inside", "DoIn");
            sendData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(display_clicked_load.this);
            dlgAlert.setMessage("Quotation Send Successfully");
            dlgAlert.setTitle("Quotation Confirmation");
            dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
            dlgAlert.create().show();
        }
    }


    public void sendData() {
        try {
            String ssendoffer;
            String email;
          //  email=getIntent().getStringExtra("loginemail");

            EditText sendoffer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sendoffer);
            ssendoffer=sendoffer.getText().toString();
            loginemail=global.email1;
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.testsite.com/folder/myfile.php");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(13);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("amount", ssendoffer));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",loginemail));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("quotation_id",id));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse hresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("error....", e + "");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("error.......", e + "");
        }

    }
    private void mLockScreenRotation() {
        // Stop the screen orientation changing during an event
        switch (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation) {
            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
                this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                break;
            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
                this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkJ5u.jpg)

Comment: Please don't use rubbish to get around the min character limit. If you can't find enough words to explain your issue then you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: This question will not be of any help to anyone in the future.

Comment: Its a warning not a error

Answer (score 0):

```
 String t= getResources().getString(R.string.shipping_time, shipping_time.toString());
 /* loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(t)); */
```

Quite simply you defined variable `t` but commented out where you used it. This is not an error, this is a warning.

In the future, search for "t=" or if you use common coding standards "t =" through the Find feature (typically Ctrl+F).  I'm not sure how this was difficult, the variables are alphabetized and I'm sure your IDE put a squiggle under it.

Comment: Thank you for your help,

I commented the code as you told me but I got now only the second string displayed on my screen.

String s= getResources().getString(R.string.shipping_date, shipping_date.toString());
        loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
        String t= getResources().getString(R.string.shipping_time, shipping_time.toString());
        loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(t));

Expand snippet

string.xml:

<string name="shipping_date">1 it: </string>
    <string name="shipping_time">2 it </string>

Expand snippet

here a screenshot:
https://files.fm/f/u4bckjh5